# Apple App Review Demo Account with SMS token login

Tags: ios, sms, app-store, review

I like to publish an app for iOS. The Apple Review Process asks for a demo account. This I can provide. But we have an 2factor login with an token, send by SMS, as the 2nd factor.

My question is, to which Phone number I can send the SMS? How does Apple handle this? Apple didn't answer until now.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue last year ago. what you need to do is to explain them in the notes section what they need to do in order to login to your app. At the end the app is tested by people who have phone access. 
Another option is to create some user ahead on the database something like **tester** and this user will be verified with a **fixed** code and in the note just write them the user email/password and the code that they need to fill in

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means, that during the review process, Apple will give me a phone number, which I have to configure to the test account?
Setting a fix TAN is not possible in the production env.